# Another .Net consuming a Java WSDL question

Tags: java, .net, web-services

This may have already been answered and I just can't find it so feel free to point if needed.

I have a JAVA WSDL endpoint that I can successfully use to generate a reference. I have also used the WSDL sent from the programmers of this end point and again was successful in creating class files to use.

However when I create the objects needed to feed this service, in both cases, I receive an error that he cannot use the payload that I am sending.

Looking at it using the SoapUI tool it seems that his service is expecting some more information in the payload tags that does not seem to make into my classes.

Example: I can create `<Tag1></Tag1>` but he needs `<init:Tag1></init:Tag1>`

I don't know where the "init" prefix is getting dropped.

I am using VS 2010 and generating a simple web reference. Any tips would be helpful at this point.

Comment: That `init` has to be defined in the message and it means that `Tag1` is from some namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I approach these problems is this:

use a same-technology client to connect to the service. 
Trace the message on the wire. If ncessary strip out signatures and encryption so that you can get a readable XML message.

now, use the different-technology client (in this case .NET) to build client-side stubs and connect to the service. Trace the message on the wire.

Compare the two, and tweak the different-technology client to get it to match.

I use Fiddler2 to captures the traces of the HTTP messages.  If you are not using HTTP then you will need something else.

---

Keep in mind, what you want is not string equality, but equivalence in the XML infoset.

An element like `<init:Tx>` may be equivalent to `<Tx>`, if the default namespace in the latter case matches the init namespace in the former.  If you don't quite get what this means, then you need to read up on xml namespaces and get comfortable with the concepts.

In many many cases, I've found that it's XML namespace disagreement issues that cause the lack of interoperability. In one case I found that a missing slash on a namespace (http://foo/bar rather than http://foo/bar/) was enough to cause communication to fail.  Figuring out what to tweak in order to get the actual message  to match the requirement message is somewhat of a black art - I don't know how to explain it.

in some cases I resort to doctoring the WSDL document to get the different-technology client to do what I want.

good luck.

Comment: Yeah I agree but was reaching for an answer to a question that I have since found out I didn't need to ask. :-)

I found out that it was the Java folks that could not handle the xs:date format that was the issue. I was trying anything.

But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have since figured out that using the 4.0 svcutil.exe is the best thing in the world for seeing these issues. Again as I stated in a comment above, I figured out that it was merely a namespace issue and it wasn't .Net that was having the issue but the Java on the other end.

Hopfully this will make it easier to see usinf the specific 4.0 generator...

```
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\svcutil.exe" /async http://SomeExternalWeb/ExtService.svc?wsdl /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /n:*,MyNS.Messaging.Services
```

I love the class generation over the reference generation any day.